# Script Python se cierra sin mostrar resultados al invocar librería Excel

Tags: python, excel

Estoy intentando hacer un script que reconozca la ruta donde se ejecuta, esto con el fin de ejecutar una tarea diferente por ruta.

```
import msvcrt
import os

ruta = str(os.getcwd())
if "\\MUSICA" in ruta:
    print("Estas en el directorio Musica")
elif "\\PELIS" in ruta:
    print("Estas en el directorio Pelis")
else:
    print("La ruta no se reconoce")

msvcrt.getch()
```

Este script lo guardo con el nombre **rutas.py** y al ejecutar con doble clic, en pantalla CMD muestra un mensaje segun recorra `IF`, hasta ahí no hay problema.
El script al final va a trabajar con archivos **EXCEL** por lo tanto al principio debo importar `openpyxl` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import msvcrt
import os

ruta = str(os.getcwd())
if "\\MUSICA" in ruta:
    print("Estas en el directorio Musica")
elif "\\PELIS" in ruta:
    print("Estas en el directorio Pelis")
else:
    print("La ruta no se reconoce")

msvcrt.getch()
```

Con solo añadir esa línea donde se importa la librería para trabajar con archivos *EXCEL* el script no funciona correctamente. Al ejecutar con doble clic muestra menos de un segundo una pantalla negra y desaparece al instante y no logro ver los print de las condicionales `IF`. Pero si ejecuto desde CMD de la siguiente manera **(python rutas.py)** ahí si funciona. pero esa manera de ejecutar no seria comodo para usuarios windows.

He añadido `msvcrt.getch()` para que no se cierre automaticamente la ventana CMD y funciona bien  cuando no se importa `openpyxl`.

Alguna forma de evitar que se cierre automaticamente la ventana CMD cuando ejecuto el script rutas.py?

Esto al final quiero convertir a un EXE y distribuir por internet gratuitamente, estos inconvenientes hacen que dia a dia piense que python no vale para crear programas para windows y solo sirven para linux donde se ejecutan los script python asi: **python script.py** eso en windows no seria genial.

Comment: He probado tu código y me funciona correctamente. Estás seguro que en todas tus pruebas importaste openpyxl? Estás seguro de que no salió ningún error durante la importación de openpyxl cuando probaste desde el cmd?

Comment: @DanteS. cuando no importo openpyxl el codigo se ejecuta con doble clic y no se sale del cmd, hasta ahi todo perfecto..el problema viene cuando importo openpyxl y hago doble clic para ejecutar el archivo python, entonces ahi se cierra inmediatamente la ventana CMD, solo si ejecuto desde CMD python rutas.py ahi si ejecuta normal. La intencion es que se ejecute con doble clic el script.

Comment: @DanteS. no arroja error de openpyxl desde cmd, se ejecuta normal desde cmd, ejecutar desde cmd no es adecuado para usuarios windows, en windows los programas deben ejecutarse con doble clic. Esa es la intencion, pero estoy teniendo problemas con lo expuesto en la pregunta.

Comment: Reemplaza la primera línea con `try: from openpyxl import load_workbook; except: pass`. Así un problema en la importación de `openpyxl` no acabará con el programa.

Comment: @AntoineL gracias por tu respuesta, lo aplique y si ahora el script al ejecutar con doble clic ya no se cierra.